# ¿Como dividir la información de un array y enviar la a otro array

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo este array en Javascript:

```
autos = [["rojo", "sedan", "ferrari"], ["verde", "coupe", "ferrari"], ["amarillo", "sedan", "ferrari"], ["azul", "sedan", "mazda"], ["verde", "sedan", "mazda"]]
```

lo que yo estoy tratando de hacer es crear un array multidimensional donde tenga la información del primer array pero que me quede así:

```
autosSeparados[0] = [["rojo", "sedan", "ferrari"], ["verde", "coupe", "ferrari"], ["amarillo", "sedan", "ferrari"]]

autosSeparados[1] = [["azul", "sedan", "mazda"], ["verde", "sedan", "mazda"]]
```

El criterio de separación que los que tengan **Ferrari** queden en una posición del array y los que tengan **mazda** pasen a la posición siguiente.

gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Algo mas o menos asi te serviria.
Haces un for por el total de autos que tengas, dsp si el valor en el auto $i en la posicion 2 que seria la marca es igual a ferrari lo pusheas al array Ferrari sino a Mazda

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="todosLosAutos"><b>Todos los autos:</b><br></div>
<br>
<div id="ferrari"><b>Ferrari:</b><br></div>
<br>
<div id="mazda"><b>Mazda:</b><br></div>

</body>
</html>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>

var autos = [["rojo", "sedan", "ferrari"], ["verde", "coupe", "ferrari"], ["amarillo", "sedan", "ferrari"], ["azul", "sedan", "mazda"], ["verde", "sedan", "mazda"]]


var ferrari = []
var mazda = []

$("#todosLosAutos").append(autos + '<br>')

for (i = 0; i <= (autos.length - 1); i++) {
 if (autos[i][2] == 'ferrari') {
  ferrari.push(autos[i])
  $("#ferrari").append(autos[i] + '<br>')
 }
 else{
  mazda.push(autos[i])
  $("#mazda").append(autos[i] + '<br>')
 }
} 

console.log('TODOS LOS AUTOS: ' + autos)
console.log('FERRARI: ' + ferrari)
console.log('MAZDA ' + mazda)

console.log(ferrari)
console.log(mazda)

</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

espero entender bien tu pregunta:

```js
let autos = [["rojo", "sedan", "ferrari"], ["verde", "coupe", "ferrari"], ["amarillo", "sedan", "ferrari"], ["azul", "sedan", "mazda"], ["verde", "sedan", "mazda"]];
let nuevoAutos = [[],[]];
function separaAutos()  {
    
    for (i = 0; i <= (autos.length - 1); i++){
        if (autos[i][2] == 'ferrari'){
            nuevoAutos[0].push(autos[i]);
        } else {
            nuevoAutos[1].push(autos[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(nuevoAutos);
}
```

Esto te da un arreglo de dos dimenciones con los arreglos de los mazda y ferrari dentro de el:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) es así de sencillo

```js
autos = [["rojo", "sedan", "ferrari"], ["verde", "coupe", "ferrari"], ["amarillo", "sedan", "ferrari"], ["azul", "sedan", "mazda"], ["verde", "sedan", "mazda"]];

let arrFerrari = autos.filter(i => i.indexOf("ferrari") > -1);
let arrMazda = autos.filter(i => i.indexOf("mazda") > -1);

console.log(arrFerrari);
console.log(arrMazda);
```